# Does Facebook Graph API have a health-check endpoint?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am working on an application which primarily expects the **Facebook Graph API** (specifically **FB Marketing API** and **FB Insights API**) to be available 24/7.

However, for most of the day today, the Facebook Graph API has been having lots of ***"503: Server Error: The server cannot process the request due to a high load."***

I would prefer to perform a health-check before requesting an asynchronous job request to generate an FB app marketing report.

Suggestions welcomed!

Thank you.

Comment: A) Easy on the **bolding**. B) Maybe you're hitting a rate limit?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Facebook does not reveal much information about its API health status.

The only information you can get can be fetched via **https://www.facebook.com/platform/api-status/** which returns the following data:

```
{
   "current": {
      "health": number which indicates the health, the lower the better,
      "subject": "text information about current action, problems etc."
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm giving +1 for the link, but it's also worth mentioning that in my many years of experience with FB, I've NEVER seen this link admit any problems even while Facebook's APIs experience issues. It doesn't seem accurate. I've experienced a variety of errors since 10:20 ET today (such as `AuthorizationException, Code: 2: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.`), and that link still says "Facebook Platform is Healthy".

Answer (score 1):

### **As I'm learning during this major Facebook outage on Thanksgiving Day 2019...**

https://developers.facebook.com/status/dashboard/ is not reliable.

On that page, I've had "Get Email Updates" set to Yes for years, but I've *never* received emails about issues (such as the major outage right now).

In addition, that status dashboard page currently (inaccurately) says:

[image]

https://www.facebook.com/platform/api-status/ similarly has been saying:

```
{
   "current": {
      "health": 1,
      "subject": "Facebook Platform is Healthy"
   }
}
```

And my personal Facebook page fails to load, hanging like this:

[image]

What I realized eventually was that **visiting https://developers.facebook.com/status/dashboard/ in Chrome Incognito** (cache cleared, not logged-in) produced a different page, which led me to see that they've acknowledged today's major issues since "Today at 6:45 AM": https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/2287293591515186/

```
{
   "current": {
      "health": 2,
      "subject": "Increased error rates across the platform"
   }
}
```